# Really confusing issue in hawtio console - browsing queue shows the wrong messages

Tags: hawtio

I was using the hawtio console to investigate the contents of queues, and restore some messages from one of my DLQ's.

At some point, I'm not sure why, my URL in the browser switched to the following:

> http://gractivemq01:8181/hawtio/activemq/browseQueue?tab=activemq&queueName=DLQ.DataQueue&nid=root-org.apache.activemq-Broker-broker_03-Queue-SomeOtherDataQueue

Notice that the "queueName" parameter is specified and remains permanently stuck on "DLQ.DataQueue".  But as I move around in the navigation tree at the left, the "nid" parameter points to various other queues.

The end result is that the information displayed (in the body of the web page at the right of the navigation tree) is totally inconsistent. When I'm looking at "Attributes" of the queue, it will show me the details of "SomeOtherDataQueue" (thereby respecting the "nid" parameter).  But when I "Browse" messages in the queue, it ignores my "nid", and respects the "queueName" parameter in the URL.

I was only able to fix the problem by editing the URL manually and removing the paramter for "queueName".  After that the information displayed for "Attributes" and "Browse" are consistent, and respect the "nid" parameter.

> http://gractivemq01:8181/hawtio/activemq/browseQueue?tab=activemq&nid=root-org.apache.activemq-Broker-broker_03-Queue-SomeOtherDataQueue

Can anyone help me understand how that "queueName" ended up in my url and why it won't clear itself away as I browse the navigation tree?  It was very confusing that when I browsed messages in various queues, it kept showing me the same ones (from DLQ.DataQueue).  It was especially confusing that DLQ.DataQueue and DataQueue (the original) had the same messages.

Comment: Which version of Hawtio are you using, 1.5.x or 2.0.x?  I'd first try using Incognito or clearing browser cache to see if this issue still persists.

Comment: Thanks for asking.  Here is the info from "About":

hawtio version: 1.4.0.redhat-630262


jolokia version: 1.3.5


server version: Apache activemq 5.11.0.redhat-630262


I suppose I'm using a very old version of hawtio but this is what is available in the latest redhat 6.3 distribution.  Should I work with their support?